# How to custom WebView scroll behavior in MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net-core, maui

I developed an app for rendering HTML content with WebView and comments list with CollectionView in a ContentPage.

the pseudo-code like this:

```xml
<ContentPage>
    <ScrollView>
        <WebView x:Nam="WebView" Source={Binding Source} ></WebView>

        <CollectionView ItemsSource={Comments} > </CollectionView>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

I hope the WebView and CollectionView shared the same ScrollView. But there is no event and properties in WebView. I don't know where to start

=======

**The illustration:**

I'm sorry for not classifying the problem, let me illustrate it again.

[image]

This is my prototype, the red zone renders an HTML page, and the grey zone renders a CollectionView with comments, they share the same
yellow scrollbar.

The WebView always stretches its height to its content, so there is no scrollbar.

The problem is in Maui, I don't know how to disable the web view scroll down/up event. when I tap in WebView, it can not trigger the scrollbar.

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @Julian  I append more information to the question.

Comment: I still don't quite understand the problem. Do you want to be able to scroll in the WebView or do you want to disable the scrolling of the WebView? Your depiction would mean that the WebView doesn't allow scrolling and the scrollbar is used to scroll down the page, which means that the WebView moves out of view once scrolled far enough down in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

For ScrollView you can refer to the official doc: [ScrollView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview?view=net-maui-7.0). It said that:

> **ScrollView** objects should not be nested. In addition, **ScrollView** objects should not be nested with other controls that provide scrolling, such as **CollectionView**, **ListView**, and **WebView**.

However, you can put WebView and CollectionView into StackLayout. A StackLayout will often be the child of a ScrollView.

```xml
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView Source="https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui"/>

        <CollectionView x:Name="coll" >
            <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}" x:Name="nn">
                    <x:String>mono</x:String>
                    <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                    <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                    <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                    <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                    <x:String>monotone</x:String>
                    <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                    <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                    <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[ScrollView as a root layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview?view=net-maui-7.0#scrollview-as-a-root-layout).

Comment: This won't work, because the WebView needs to have a `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` when nested inside a StackLayout, as per the documentation. It's better to use a Grid, which doesn't have this requirement.

Comment: I have tested it(add WidthRequest and HeightRequest for WebView ), but it didn't work well...